# Passing An Uninstantiated Template Name into a Function Template Expansion

Tags: c++, templates, functor

I have the following code defining a Functor template and the function
running_op, which takes an array, it's length and a functor to apply
to the list:

```
  template <class Type>
  struct SumFunctor {
    Type sum;
    SumFunctor() : sum(0) {};
    Type operator()(Type next) {
      return sum += next;
    }
  };

  template <class Container, class Functor>
  inline Container running_op(Container& container, Functor functor) {
    transform(container.begin(), container.end(), container.begin(), functor);
    return container;  
  }
```

This is used in the following way:

```
  list<float> a({1,1,1,1});
  running_op(a, SumFunctor<float>());
```

What I would like to be able to do to avoid having type the name of
the container in the instantiated functor is use it as so:

```
  list<float> a({1,1,1,1});
  running_op(a, SumFunctor);
```

Since the contained type of a can be found in the running_op template
using Container::value_type I would like to do something as follows
(which does not work) to instantiate the functor of appropriate type:

```
  template <class Container, class Functor>
  inline Container running_op(Container& container, Functor functor) {
    typedef typename Container::value_type ContainerType;
    transform(container.begin(), container.end(), container.begin(), functor<ContainerType>());
    return container;
  }
```

Is there any way that I can pass an
uninstantiated template to another template for later instantiation?
Is there a special keyword I should use other than class in the
template parameter list (template did not work in this case)?  Really
I just want to pass in a symbol which is the functor template name; is
that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template templates.

```
  template <template <class> class Functor, class Container>
  inline Container running_op(Container& container) {
    typedef typename Container::value_type ContainerType;
    transform(container.begin(), container.end(), container.begin(), functor<ContainerType>());
    return container;
  }


  running_op<sum_function>(a);
```

If you want that certain syntax you can use macros, although I don't recommend it.

```
#define running_op(a, b) running_op_<b>(a)
```

Comment: I think I did try something similar to that and it's close to what I was wanting but I'm still curious if I can do it the way that I outlined in the question without the macro.

Comment: Nah, close enough. Thanks for the answer.